# vb.net Postgresql Database, using DataTable and display bitmap in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, datagridview, datatable, bitmap

I am using a Postgresql, and I would like to store a status value. These values should be of type integer (0 = OK, 1 = Not OK e.g.). 
But I don't want to display these values as integer in my datagridview, I would like to display some small icons or bitmaps.

But how am I able to do this? 
If I am using a DataColumn with Bitmap Type, I can't use the Integer type in my database.

This is how I fill my DataTable with the SQL data.
dtRecord is assigned to my DataGridview.

```
sda = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(pgCommand)
        sda.Fill(dtRecord)
```

This was a test - but I can't insert the integer values from the SQL Database

```
Dim column1 As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Status")
    column1.DataType = GetType(Bitmap)
```

Can someone give me any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have two options. 1. Handle the CellFormatting Event and for that column, draw the bitmap based on the value. Or 2. Use a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. Use the combo box to draw the image

Comment: Hello, I tried option 1, but I have the problem, that I can't change the columntype to a imagecolumn afterwards, is there an option for that? DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).ValueType = GetType(Bitmap) doesn't change anything for me.

Comment: My apologies for the slow answer below. I have now had the time to produce a full working example of how to achieve what you are looking for. Please do take a look and see if it matches your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fully working sample of how to load an image from the disk based on a value in the grid and display that image. In addition to the code below, you will need to drop a `DataGridView` on to the form from the Designer

```
Public Class Form1
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    InitialiseGridView()

    InitialiseDataTable()

    DataGridView1.DataSource = RecordsDataTable
End Sub

Dim RecordsDataTable As DataTable

Private Sub InitialiseGridView()
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    AddHandler DataGridView1.CellFormatting, AddressOf DataGridView1_CellFormatting

    DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
    Dim dgvImageColumn As New DataGridViewImageColumn()
    dgvImageColumn.Name = "dgvImageColumn"
    dgvImageColumn.DataPropertyName = "dgvImageColumn"
    dgvImageColumn.HeaderText = "Status"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvImageColumn)

    Dim dgvTextColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    dgvTextColumn.Name = "dgvTextColumn"
    dgvTextColumn.DataPropertyName = "dgvTextColumn"
    dgvTextColumn.HeaderText = "Other Text"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvTextColumn)
End Sub

Private Sub InitialiseDataTable()
    RecordsDataTable = New DataTable()

    RecordsDataTable.Columns.Add("dgvImageColumn", GetType(Integer))
    RecordsDataTable.Columns.Add("dgvTextColumn", GetType(String))

    RecordsDataTable.Rows.Add({1, "one"})
    RecordsDataTable.Rows.Add({0, "two"})
    RecordsDataTable.Rows.Add({1, "three"})
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)
    Dim thisDGV As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    If (thisDGV.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "dgvImageColumn") Then
        Dim newImage As Image
        If (e.Value.ToString() = "0") Then
            newImage = Bitmap.FromFile("D:\Projects\Graphics\GreenDot.png")
        Else
            newImage = Bitmap.FromFile("D:\Projects\Graphics\RedDot.png")
        End If
        e.Value = newImage
        e.FormattingApplied = True
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

This will give you a `DataGridView` that looks like:

[image]